Vuelidate 2 not updating $model when computed list is provided
I'm running Vuelidate 2 in Vue 3 with vue/compat, but when I'm trying to get vuelidate working in my component it seems like the $model is not getting updated accordingly with any change in the input, here is my setup:
I have a collection of elements coming from my backend in this format:
[
  { "id": 1, "start_time": "09:00:00", "finish_time": "13:00:00", "date": null }, 
  { "id": 2, "start_time": "09:00:00", "finish_time": "13:00:00", "date": null },
  { "id": 3, "start_time": "09:00:00", "finish_time": "12:00:00", "date": "31/05/2024" }
]

The backend is expecting this same format to store the data, so I'm stuck with this format sending it back into the server.
Now, I need to display the elements which DO have a set date in one side of the screen in my front-end and the ones that DO NOT have a date set in another side, to do this I've created a computed element that will group them by if it has a set date or not and set them into an object like this:
{
    'timed_slots': [  
        { "id": 1, "start_time": "09:00:00", "finish_time": "13:00:00", "date": null }, 
        { "id": 2, "start_time": "09:00:00", "finish_time": "13:00:00", "date": null },
    ],
    'dated_slots': [
        { "id": 3, "start_time": "09:00:00", "finish_time": "12:00:00", "date": "31/05/2024" }
    ]
}

This is my computed element:
const slotsData = computed(() =>
    Object.groupBy(
        props.value.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, index })),
        ({ date }) => (date ? 'dated_slots' : 'timed_slots'),
    ),
);

Everything works fine and the constant is reactive, so now I'm passing the correct key to each of my components (the component is the same) to display the data:
<slots-table :data="slotsData.timed_slots" />
<slots-table :data="slotsData.dated_slots" />

My slots-table component is really simple and looks like this:
<table class="table m-t-sm slot-builder-component">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th v-if="showDatepicker">Date</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>Finish Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(slot, index) in data" :key="index">
            <td v-if="showDatepicker">
                <div
                    class="form-group"
                >
                    <input type="text" v-model="slot.date" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div
                        class="input-group b-timeselector"
                    >
                        <input type="text" v-model="slot.start_time" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div
                        class="input-group b-timeselector"
                    >
                        <input type="text" v-model="slot.finish_time" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

Inside this component I'm setting my validations like this:
const rules = {
    $each: helpers.forEach({
        start_time: { required },
        finish_time: { required },
        appointment_reason_id: { required },
        max_appointments: { required },
        date: { requiredIfCustomSession: requiredIf(props.showDatepicker) },
    }),
};

const v = useVuelidate(rules, props.data, { $autoDirty: true });

But when I'm trying to add a new item in the list, vuelidate is not updating correctly for some reason and I'm getting an error as it looks like the v object does not have my newest added element in its component.
You can take a look on a playcode I created in this link:
https://playcode.io/1842471
Hopefully someone can help me out understanding why.
Thanks in advance.

slotsData computed isn't supposed to be mutated, and the changes would be unconditionally discarded on recalculation. It's shallowly reactive because this is not regular usage for it. A computed can generally be expressed with a combination of writable ref and a watcher, this is a requirement in this case:
const slotsData = ref()

watchEffect(() => {
  slotsData.value = Object.groupBy(...)
});

This still resets slotsData on initialData change. In case this is not the intention then initialData should remain intact and the way addSlot works needs to be revised.
It's also a bad practice to mutate data prop. slotsData is supposed to be mutated only in a parent. This requires slots-table to have its own local state that's synchronized with the parent, or the changes to data should be emitted to the parent:
 <input type="text" :value="slot.start_time"
   @input="$emit('changeData', { key: 'start_time', value: $event.target.value, index }) />

And there should be enough data to modify slotsData:
<slots-table :data="slotsData.timed_slots" 
  @changeData="changeData('timed_slots', $event)" />

...

changeData(type, { key, value, index } ) {
  slotsData.value[type][index][key] = value
}

Also index isn't reliable enough to be used as a key.

Thanks Estus, leaving aside the fact that the input v-models in slots-table should not be there (that's actually already fixed hehe), my main issue is that I need all changes to be in the initialData value, as that's ultimately the array I'm going to be sending to the server, by doing this approach I'm only changing the 'slotsData` generated Object and not the correct source data.

I'm unsure if the approach suggested in the answer works for you. Does it? initialData name is a tad misleading as it's not "initial" but "regular" when you start making changes to it. Any way, it can be any way you need, as long as changes to parent's state are made only in the parent. If request payload needs to differ from state somehow, e.g. in a way initialData and slotsData differ by their shape, it could be calculated once on submit, and there would be only one reactive data object that's more comfortable to use with the form

Yeah I was afraid that was the only way I could do that, I was just hoping for a cheeky way to achieve the desired behaviour that I haven't seen, but yeah it looks like I need to reformat the object on submit, thanks Estus

You can use a computed, this likely would be the opposite to what you tried, ref() should be a state that's suitable for forms as is, and computed() would be a state for payload, but this would be a waste of resources because it needs to be calculated only once on submit, not on every form change
